# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: angular

Estou recebendo um erro ao entrar na rota bug-details, antes mesmo de clicar no routerlink para tentar acessar edit-bug, que é a minha intenção. O erro é:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (BugDetailComponent.html:14)

Podem me dar uma ajuda? O código está em https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sm7joh

Comment: Você poderia dar mais detalhes? De que objeto você está tentando usar o `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Declaração

```
bug: any;
```

## Correção

```
const bug = bugDetails[i];
//para
this.bug = bugDetails[i];
```

como você declarou como uma `constant` o template não consegue referenciar

Comment: Obrigado Willian!

Comment: qual o motivo do down vote?